# Column not copied with transportable tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, datapump

I have a tablespace that I copy from one Oracle instance to another. I use transportable tablespace to do so.

The problem I have is that values of 2 columns in a table are not being copied in the new tablespace.

I have a table with 57 columns. 2 columns are giving me trouble. I dont see any NULL value in those columns in the source DB, but in the destination DB, all I have is NULL values for those 2 columns.

I made sure those columns are not  encrypted.

Here is the column definitions :

```
COLA NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
COLB NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
```

Anybody has an idea why those columns are not being copied?

Comment: How does `COLA` get created without a data type?

Comment: My bad, it was a wrong cut/paste. NUMBER is actually defined on that row.